# Inversion of Control and Choices

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I am trying to use Inversion of Control correctly. My app is working fine. I am using Unity as the IoC container. However, I think I am going wrong when there is a choice on which concrete class to use.

In this example, I have a class that gets data from a specific data source. Depending on the file type, I call a data accessor class.

This service class checks the type, does a switch, and then selects which concrete class to use.

However, it seems I am breaking the IoC principles here, by 'newing' something in the class. I no longer inject into this service class, because at this point, I haven't decided which file type I'm working with. So I had to comment out the 'injection', and rather hard code it.

Here's a code extract.

```
public class DataService : IDataService
    {
        IFileReader _fileReader;
        public DataService(IFileReader fileReader)
        {
            // _fileReader = fileReader;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns reporting data based on a group of export files.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="files">A list of files to analyse</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private List<RawFileData> GetRawData(string[] files)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // validate files exists.
                switch (GetFileType(Path.GetFileName(file)))
                {
                    case "CSV":
                         {
                             fileIsOK = true;
                             _fileReader = new CSVileConnector();
                             break;
                         }
                     case "TXT":
                         {
                             fileIsOK = true;
                             _fileReader = new TXTFileConnector();
                             break;
                         }
                     default:
                         break;
                 }
                 if (fileIsOK)
                 {
                     var finedata = _fileReader.ReadData(file);
                     data.Add(new RawFileData
                     {
                         DataItems = finedata,
                         FileName = file
                     });
                }
            }

            return data;
        }
```

Is this the right way to handle this type of situation? Where, on class creation, I'm not sure which child class to 'depend' on? And then decide it in logic, and new up the correct Concrete class?

Comment: Maybe ioc is just principles not rules.

Comment: Yeah, this could be true - hence why I called it principles. But it's often good to stick to principles if you can. I'm checking to see if what am doing is correct - or is there a better way to do it. It might be - don't let the service layer decide on the data type.. this should be done in the data layer. In chich case, my 'switch' moves down a layer... and IoC is back in play here. But then I have the same issue in the data layer. I need to new up the right concrete class down there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement could be to separate the choosing of the reader from the reading itself--a private method called `IFileReader _getDataReader(string filename)`. So in your foreach loop you say `var reader = _getDataReader(filename);`. There's no good reason for the reader to be a private property in your class since it isn't constructed, can change continuously, and the scope of its use is limited to `GetRawData`. What you *could* consider injecting through the constructor is a class with `GetDataReader(string)` in its interface definition. That itself could hold a private `Dictionary<string, Type>` which would have as its keys file extensions and then the reader of that file as the value. You could even configure that in your app.config if yau wanted. That's known as the [Service Locator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx) pattern.

There are good arguments that [this is actually an anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) for various reasons. It might also be argued that you're over thinking it--since you only have two choices and it's easy to read this way--but separating the choosing of the reader from the reading itself at least puts you in a place where it's easier to change if you need.

Comment: Thanks Chad. I like the separation of the _getDataReader bit. That makes much neater code. I agree about the 'over-thinking' bit and the service locator. One requirement of our team is to not over-engineer it, but create idiomatic code that's easy to read and maintain. And it's OK that the constructor of the class doesn't have any injection? The injection is now deferred to the filetype. So the whole Inversion of Control is still valid - right?